# Problema en widget Text('Mensaje') En flutter

Tags: flutter

No me funciona en ningún contexto y me da este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me ha funcionado siempre

Answer (score 0):

revista si importaste el paquete(package) de material:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

En caso de que no, trata de reiniciar tu editor de vscode. Muchas veces se traba por las extensiones instaladas.